# Multi Column Menu

Tags: 8, navigation

Is there some easy way to create a multi-column (or grid) menu, eg:

```
item 1   item 4   item 7
item 2   item 5   item 8
item 3   item 6
```

There are no parents in this menu.

I would rather not install a module just to do this.

You can do it easily with views, is there no way built in to do it with menus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the menu twig with an additional row loop with 3 items per row:

**menu.html.twig**

```
  {% if items %}
    {% for row in items|batch(3) %}
    <ul class="row">
      {% for item in row %}
        <li{{ item.attributes }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul> 
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

This is a simplified version for only one level as your menu items have no parents.

Answer (score 2):

There is no build-in way to set Drupal's menus to fill multiple columns from the UI, however, since menus in Drupal are html lists, you can use css to break them into multiple columns:

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
```

This will work in all browsers save Internet Explorer 9 or lower. If you need to support old versions of IE, you would need to use a little js helper like [Columnizer jQuery Plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) or [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/).

The advantage of this approach is, that you can use media queries to set the number of columns to fit different devices/screen widths.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that works for CSS3 only? Internet explorer 10+? Would it work for IE9?

Comment: Already updated my answer ;) No, it wouldn't, but I listed two js which ensure backward compatibility.